# Why is python saying dictionary is not defined?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, classification

I'm currently applying some machine learning code to analyze emails from the enron dataset using the following code in python:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, GaussianNB, BernoulliNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC, NuSVC, LinearSVC

def make_dictionary(train_dir):
    emails = [os.path.join(train_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(train_dir)]    
    all_words = []       
    for mail in emails:    
        with open(mail) as m:
            for i,line in enumerate(m):
                if i == 2:
                    words = line.split()
                    all_words += words
    dictionary = Counter(all_words)
    return dictionary
list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()
for item in list_to_remove:
    if item.isalpha() == False:
        del dictionary[item]
    elif len(item) == 1:
        del dictionary[item]
    dictionary = dictionary.most_common(3000)
train_dir = 'train-mails'
dictionary = make_Dictionary(train_dir)


def extract_features(mail_dir):
    files = [os.path.join(mail_dir,fi) for fi in os.listdir(mail_dir)]
    features_matrix = np.zeros((len(files),3000))
    docID = 0;
    for fil in files:
        with open(fil) as fi:
            for i,line in enumerate(fi):
                if i == 2:
                    words = line.split()
                for word in words:
                  wordID = 0
                  for i,d in enumerate(dictionary):
                    if d[0] == word:
                      wordID = i
                      features_matrix[docID,wordID] = words.count(word)
            docID = docID + 1
        return features_matrix

train_labels = np.zeros(702)
train_labels[351:701] = 1
train_matrix = extract_features(train_dir)

model1 = MultinomialNB()
model2 = LinearSVC()
model1.fit(train_matrix,train_labels)
model2.fit(train_matrix,train_labels)

test_dir = 'test-mails'
test_matrix = extract_features(test_dir)
test_labels = np.zeros(260)
test_labels[130:260] = 1
result1 = model1.predict(test_matrix)
result2 = model2.predict(test_matrix)
print confusion_matrix(test_labels,result1)
print confusion_matrix(test_labels,result2)
```

However, every time I run it, it says that dictionary is not defined and I can not figure out why it doesn't want to work. I've indented the areas which need it and I have the correct modules imported but it still doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix this would be helpful.

Comment: `list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()` where is dictionary coming from?  You might want to read [Python scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: I don't actually do python scripting, however, it looks to me you are calling "list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()" before you are actually defining "dictionary = make_Dictionary(train_dir)". Not sure if thats it but maybe?

Comment: Move `train_dir =...` and `dictionary = ...` above the `list_to_remove = ...` line and you won't get that error anymore. Voting to close for typographical error.

Comment: I tried moving them to above the list_to_remove = section and it came up saying make_dictionary is not defined now

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary = make_Dictionary(train_dir)`
should be `dictionary = make_dictionary(train_dir)`

python is case sensitive. `D` should be `d`.